# Google Maps API - Having my markers link to new pages

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Okay so I am having troubles making the custom markers on my map link to new pages on my website.

Here is my array containing all the needed info about each marker:

```
            var locations = [
            ['Passage Island', 49.343085, -123.305938, 'tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/passage.html'],
            ['Point Atkinson', 49.329925, -123.264994, 'tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/patkinson.html']
        ];
```

And here is my for loop that creates each marker, and *should* be adding an event listener to each marker:

```
var markers = [], i;

        for(i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
                map: map,
                url: locations[i][3]  //not sure why this isn't linking to anything
            }));

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function(){
                window.location.href = markers.url; 
            });
        }
```

For some reason my markers aren't linking to anything at all. I'm not too sure why. Finding examples for this kind of thing online seem to be few and far between. Any help would be appreciated! 
If you need to see more code, here is my github: https://github.com/tylerkohlhaas/waterscout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var locations = [
            ['Passage Island', 49.343085, -123.305938, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/passage.html'],
            ['Point Atkinson', 49.329925, -123.264994, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/patkinson.html']
        ];


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

        var i;

        for(i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
                map: map,
                url: locations[i][3],  //not sure why this isn't linking to anything,
                zIndex: 20
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function(){
                window.location.href = markers.url;
                console.log("here we go");
            });
        }
```

I addead a http:// to the locations and changed your definition of a marker. The EventListener was not working, you can easily do a console.log -  also take the z-index into consideration. Works for me now.

best

M

Comment: Thank you for the help! The change that made it work was you creating the marker variable inside the for loop rather than outside. I suppose that makes sense now that I see it. Thank you!